# structure as field of template class c++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm newbie in C++. I'm learning how to use templates.
My goal is a possibility to create both "int" and "SpacePlace" PropertyType object.
The next code doesn't work, because of error "C2228" (MSVC 2010) in every string of method "GrabCoordinates(...)".

```
struct SpacePlace
{
    float x,y,z;
};

template <class SomeType> class PropertyType
{
    SomeType variable;

    public:
    void GrabCoordinates(SpacePlace *obj)
    {
            variable.x=obj->x;
            /*varibale.x is wrong, "left of '.identifier' must
             have class/struct/union"*/
            variable.y=obj->y;//similiar error
            variable.z=obj->z;//similiar error
    }
    ...//some code
 };

  int main()
  {
          PropertyType <SpacePlace> coordinates;
          PropertyType <int> just_a_number;
          ...//some code
   }
```

I just want to know, is it possible reach my goal? Or fields in templates in c++ should be only "simple types"? Sorry for my English :) Thank you.

Comment: When you write `variable.x`, you implicitly require the type of `x` to be a class type and have a member named `x`, for thich this assignment is legal. This of course isn't true if `variable` is of type `int`. N.B. This isn't the entire story. If you *don't use `GrabCoordinates`*, it should work fine.

Comment: To point this out: If you remove the two `...`, then your code compiles. Only if you call `just_a_number.GrabCoordinates(something);`, then you'll get an error.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is little, but most important part of programm :( I wanted to create class for keeping data with all possible types, but I've failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have it like this :

```
template <class SomeType> class PropertyType
{
    SomeType variable;

    public:
    void GrabCoordinates(const SomeType& obj)
    {
            variable=obj;

    }
    //..some code
 };
```

Comment: And in fact you *should* have it like this, and delegate the assignment to the type itself.

Comment: "'conversion' : cannot convert from 'type1' to 'type2'" after changes.
It can't convert "SpacePlace" to "int". I think, this is result of my bad idea. I wil try to solve problem, thank you for idea :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `PropertyType <int>`: In this instantiation of the template, `variable` is declared as an int, so you end up with something like

int variable;
//...
variable.x=obj->y;

Which fails because an `int` has no `.x` member.

In general, the type you instantiate in the template must be able to fulfill all the "obligations" you impose on it in the template code. In your case, this is the `.x` member, but it could also be assignment, comparison, increment, etc.

Comment: I should use only cognate types? For example, structures with two fields, or structures with three filds?

Answer (score 0):

For `PropertyType <int>`, the `variable` is of type `int`. So it is as if you tried:

```
int variable;
variable.x = ojb->x;
```